# C# Enrollment System schedule conflict

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a problem in my system, I want to put an error after I insert a value into the database. This is my sample for better explanation.

I have two table which is Enlistment and Subject, and this are the sample value .

[image: My Table with sample Value]

Now my problem is I want to put and error my the time will be the same or conflict for example :
I will ad a value on the Enlistment table which is this .

[image: I insert new value to Enlistment Table]

Now this will create an Error because as you can see on the Subject table ,
offerNo = 102 Have the same value of StartTime, EndTime and Days of inserted value in the Enlistment table. Then if it is not the same value it will just insert into the table without getting an error. Can you give me some codes , on how to solve this, Thank you for the help

This is my code for precedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[addSubject]
(
@newStudID int,
@newofferNo int
)
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION

declare @newStart datetime
set @newStart = (select StartTime from Subject where offerNo = @newofferNo)
declare @newEnd datetime
set @newEnd = (select EndTime from Subject where offerNo = @newOfferNo)
declare @newDays varchar(50)
set @newDays = (select StudDays from Subject where offerNo = @newOfferNo)

insert into Enlistment values(@newStudID, @newStudID, @newOfferNo, @newStart, @newEnd, @newDays)

UPDATE Subject
SET Capacity = Capacity - 1
WHERE offerNo = @newofferNo

COMMIT TRANSACTION 
END
```

Now this is my code in the Front End

```
        conn = koneksyon.getConnect();
        conn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select a.offerNo  from Enlistment a, Subject b where a.offerNo = b.offerNo AND a.offerNo ='" + textEnrollOfferNo.Text + "' AND a.studID = '" + textEnrollID.Text + "'", conn);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            offerNo = dr[0].ToString();
        }
        dr.Dispose();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select offerNo,Capacity,StartTime, EndTime,StudDays from Subject  where offerNo ='" + textEnrollOfferNo.Text +  "'", conn);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            offNo = dr[0].ToString();
            capacity = dr[1].ToString();
            start = dr[2].ToString();
            end = dr[3].ToString();
            day = dr[4].ToString();

        }
        dr.Dispose();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select StartTime, StudDays from Enlistment where StudDays =  '" + day + "'", conn);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            START = dr[0].ToString();
            DAY = dr[1].ToString();
        }
        dr.Dispose();


        cmd.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
        if (textEnrollOfferNo.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Input Offer No.", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            textEnrollOfferNo.Clear();
            textEnrollOfferNo.Focus();
        }
        else if (textEnrollOfferNo.Text == offerNo)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot insert duplicate schedules", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            textEnrollOfferNo.Clear();
            textEnrollOfferNo.Focus();
        }
        else if (offNo != textEnrollOfferNo.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Offer No doesn't exist!", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            textEnrollOfferNo.Clear();
            textEnrollOfferNo.Focus();
        }
        else if (textEnrollOfferNo.Text == offNo && Convert.ToInt32(capacity) == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Subject is closed!", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            textEnrollOfferNo.Clear();
            textEnrollOfferNo.Focus();
        }
        else if( (textEnrollOfferNo.Text != offerNo  && START == start && DAY == day) || (offerNo != textEnrollOfferNo.Text && start == START && day == DAY) || (textEnrollOfferNo.Text != offerNo && START == start && day == DAY) || (textEnrollOfferNo.Text != offerNo && start == START && DAY == day))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Subject is conflict!", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            textEnrollOfferNo.Clear();
            textEnrollOfferNo.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            //Button Add Subject for Student
            conn = koneksyon.getConnect();
            conn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("AddSubject", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


            cmd.Parameters.Add("@newStudID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textEnrollID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@newofferNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textEnrollOfferNo.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();

            MessageBox.Show("Added Successfully! ", "SUCCESS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            conn = koneksyon.getConnect();
            conn.Open();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select a.offerNo,b.subj,b.description,b.units,b.StartTime, b.EndTime,b.room,b.StudDays from Enlistment a, Subject b where a.offerNo = b.offerNo AND a.studID ='" + textEnrollID.Text + "' ORDER BY a.StudDays, a.StartTime", conn);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string startTime = dr[4].ToString();
                string EndTIme = dr[5].ToString();
                DateTime start1 = DateTime.Parse(startTime);
                DateTime end1 = DateTime.Parse(EndTIme);

                string Time = start1.ToString("h:mm") + " - " + end1.ToString("h:mm tt");

                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr[0], dr[1], dr[2], dr[3], Time, dr[6], dr[7]);
            }
            dr.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();

            conn = koneksyon.getConnect();
            conn.Open();

            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select sum(b.units) from Enlistment a, Subject b where a.offerNo = b.offerNo AND a.studID ='" + textEnrollID.Text + "'", conn);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                textTotalUnits.Text = dr[0].ToString();
            }
            dr.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        dr.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: @scsimon thanks for the edit sir

Comment: So why would there be an error? Is this a constraint you are looking to implement? What determines an error?

Comment: @scsimon my bad sir, What I mean is, The Error  will be Displayed on a message box if the inserted value will have the same value of start time, endtime and days, then if not , It will just insert the value

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are using the C# code,what technology you are using with C# to connect to database? (EF? L2S? , OR Mapping, Raw sql?...etc) but you can check using a stored procedure or a raw query if there is any conflict using this query

```
declare @studentId  int = 1000,
        @offerId int = 102,
        @existOffer int 
select @existOffer = t.OfferNo
from Subject c, Subject t
where c.OfferNo = @offerId 
and   c.StartTime = t.StartTime
and   c.Days = t.Days
and   c.OfferNo!= t.OfferNo
and exists(
   select 1
   from Enlistment e 
   where e.OfferNo = t.OfferNo and e.StudentID = @studentId
)
```

now if `@existOffer` is not null , this means there is a conflict and you can display a message that there is a conflict to the end user.

Hope this will help you

Comment: Im using, SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO(EXPRESS) ma'am